# calculate the avg salary of the emp having the same number of letters in emp_name per state

Tags: mysql, hive

We have a single table below ..........

```
+-------------+----------+-----+------+---+-----+
|employee_name|department|state|salary|age|bonus|
+-------------+----------+-----+------+---+-----+
|James        |Sales     |NP   |90000 |34 |10000|
|Michael      |Sales     |NP   |86000 |56 |20000|
|Corne        |Sales     |NP   |86000 |56 |20000|
|Robert       |Sales     |CA   |81000 |30 |23000|
|Maria        |Finance   |CA   |90000 |24 |23000|
|Raman        |Finance   |CA   |99000 |40 |24000|
|Scott        |Finance   |NY   |83000 |36 |19000|
|Jen          |Finance   |NY   |79000 |53 |15000|
|Jeff         |Marketing |DC   |80000 |25 |18000|
|Kumar        |Marketing |DC   |91000 |50 |21000|
+-------------+----------+-----+------+---+-----+
```

Need output like this

```
+-------------+-----+-----------+
|employee_name|state|avg(salary |
+-------------+-----+-----------+
|James        |NP   |88000      |
|Corne        |NP   |88000      |
|Maria        |CA   |90000      |
|Raman        |CA   |94500      |
|+-------------+----------+-----+
```

I have written a query - but not getting results as expected

```
select t.state, t.employee_name ,avg(salary) from temp t
join 
(select t1.state, t1.employee_name,length(t1.employee_name) from temp t1 
group by t1.state, t1.employee_name )t2
on
t.employee_name = t2.employee_name
where 
length(t.employee_name) = length(t2.employee_name)
group by t.state,t.employee_name,t.salary
```

my output is not filtering on length

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+
|state|employee_name|avg(salary)|
+-----+-------------+-----------+
|   NP|        James|    90000.0|
|   NP|      Michael|    86000.0|
|   CA|       Robert|    81000.0|
|   CA|        Maria|    90000.0|
|   CA|        Raman|    99000.0|
|   NY|        Scott|    83000.0|
|   NY|          Jen|    79000.0|
|   DC|        Kumar|    91000.0|
|   DC|         Jeff|    80000.0|
+-----+-------------+-----------+
```

Please help me in correcting my query

Comment: Not sure why they have -1 vote here .. I have tired and pasted the query there ... could you please justify

Comment: Maria and Raman should have the same avg salary because they are of the same name length and in the same state

Comment: It is not clear what filtering on length do you need. 5 characters only?

Comment: Need avg(salary) based on same length of emp_names per state... i

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic function:

```
select employee_name, state,
       avg(salary) over(partition by state, length(employee_name)) avg_salary
 from temp;
```

Demo:

```
with temp as ( --test dataset
    select 'James' employee_name ,'Sales' department, 'NP' state,90000 salary,34 age,10000 bonus union all 
    select 'Michael','Sales'     ,'NP',86000,56,20000 union all 
    select 'Corne'  ,'Sales'     ,'NP',86000,56,20000 union all 
    select 'Robert' ,'Sales'     ,'CA',81000,30,23000 union all 
    select 'Maria'  ,'Finance'   ,'CA',90000,24,23000 union all 
    select 'Raman'  ,'Finance'   ,'CA',99000,40,24000 union all 
    select 'Scott'  ,'Finance'   ,'NY',83000,36,19000 union all 
    select 'Jen'    ,'Finance'   ,'NY',79000,53,15000 union all 
    select 'Jeff'   ,'Marketing' ,'DC',80000,25,18000 union all 
    select 'Kumar'  ,'Marketing'  ,'DC',91000,50,21000 
    )
    
    select employee_name, state,
          avg(salary) over(partition by state, length(employee_name)) avg_salary
    from temp
    order by state, length(employee_name);
```

Result:

```
employee_name   state   avg_salary  
Maria           CA      94500
Raman           CA      94500
Robert          CA      81000
Jeff            DC      80000
Kumar           DC      91000
James           NP      88000
Corne           NP      88000
Michael         NP      86000
Jen             NY      79000
Scott           NY      83000
```

Comment: Not correct . Need avg(salary) based on same length of emp_names per state .. your query is giving general average salary

Comment: @Joe it is based on same length of emp_names per state

Comment: @Joe I added demo with result. Could you please have a look at result and tell me what exactly is not correct? Maybe I do not understand what should be done

Comment: it should match the length of employee i.e  Maria & Raman are in same length (letters . ie 5) and not Robert .. similarly for others .. the result for the above problem is first  2 rows only with Avg salary of the two names .

Comment: @Joe Yes, Maria and Raman have the same AVG because they are of the same length and in the same state. Robert has different AVG. Should Maria and Raman have the same AVG? Sorry I do not understand what is wroing, please have a look at the Result in my answer

Comment: @Joe Look: Maria has 90000, Raman has 99000. (90000+99000)/2 = 94500. Is this correct calculation? Robert is alone in the group, avg=salary= 81000.   Function in my query is NOT general average, it is analytic function with partition by. AVG is calculated for each group in partition by, not on the whole dataset.

Comment: Understand the question first

Comment: @Joe This is what I tried to do... and asked you about why Maria and Ramon have different AVG (in the expected output) though they have the same length and state...  Yes it is really is not clear to me, sorry